# Azure Databricks Job notification email

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I am using Databricks for ETL and I have configured the Job success and Job Failure notification email.
The email notification is working fine. 
Now, I need to create a pipeline to send the Failure notification to Service Now ticketing system which creates a tickets automatically.
The problem here is

1. The Service Now is having a webhook, is there a way to configure webhook instead of Email notification ?
2. Is there a way to modify the system generated template for the Failure notification to add few details on the email so that it can be filtered in Service Now system.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Azure Databricks uses email_notifications in the Jobs to get alerts on job start/success/failures. You can also forward these email alerts to PagerDuty, Slack, and other monitoring systems.

- [How to set up PagerDuty alerts with emails](https://www.pagerduty.com/docs/guides/email-integration-guide/)
- [How to set up Slack notification with emails](https://slack.com/intl/en-gb/help/articles/206819278-Send-emails-to-Slack)

**Reference:** [Azure Databricks - Alerts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/jobs#advanced-job-options)

Unfortunately, you cannot configure webhook instead of Email notification.

I would suggest you to provide feedback on the same:

[Azure Databricks - Feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/909463-azure-databricks)

All of the feedback you share in these forums will be monitored and reviewed by the Microsoft engineering teams responsible for building Azure.